# How to eliminate the left and right margins of a grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

If I have a grouped UITableView, it comes with a grayish border/buffer around the edge of it.  Is there any way to tell how large this buffer is, or equivalently, how big the actual white cell inside it is?

Comment: I never could find a way, and I really tried and googled (but that was several months ago). In the end I just hardcoded the values - it was like 20 points on each side. Good luck!

Comment: There's not a way to remove the border is there? I DON'T mean make the border disappear, what I mean is make the actual cell take up the entire width of the table

Comment: The problem is, I want to dynamically change the position of my table, but the tableview border changes size depending on how wide the table is

Comment: Right - you want to use the group style, that's the way it works. You could probably spin something similar using the normal style by creatively doing section headers and footers etc.

Comment: Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can eliminate the left and right margins of a grouped UITableView. Just subclass UITableViewCell. Note that if you want the margin to be something other than 0 just change the setFrame method to suit your needs.

```
//In CustomGroupedCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomGroupedCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableView *myTableView;
@end




//In CustomGroupedCell.m
#import "CustomGroupedCell.h"

@implementation CustomGroupedCell
@synthesize myTableView = _myTableView;

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    frame = CGRectMake(- [self cellsMargin] , frame.origin.y, self.myTableView.frame.size.width + 2 *[self cellsMargin], frame.size.height);
    self.contentView.frame = frame;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

- (CGFloat)cellsMargin {

    // No margins for plain table views
    if (self.myTableView.style == UITableViewStylePlain) {
        return 0;
    }

    // iPhone always have 10 pixels margin
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    CGFloat tableWidth = self.myTableView.frame.size.width;

    // Really small table
    if (tableWidth <= 20) {
        return tableWidth - 10;
    }

    // Average table size
    if (tableWidth < 400) {
        return 10;
    }

    // Big tables have complex margin's logic
    // Around 6% of table width,
    // 31 <= tableWidth * 0.06 <= 45

    CGFloat marginWidth  = tableWidth * 0.06;
    marginWidth = MAX(31, MIN(45, marginWidth));
    return marginWidth;
}

@end
```