# How do I eliminate the margin on the left side of a UITableView, without creating a gap on the right?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am targeting iOS 7 and 8, and I want to eliminate the margin appearing on the left side of the images in this UITableView below. I would even be willing to accept a solution that only works on iOS 8 if the solution is simple/elegant. (I would just live with the margin on iOS 7 as it dies out).

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

I have read through many similar questions on Stack Overflow ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107188/how-do-i-adjust-the-left-margin-for-prototype-cells-in-a-uitableview)), or ones specific to grouped UITableViews ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669678/how-to-eliminate-the-left-and-right-margins-of-a-grouped-uitableview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326953/how-to-reduce-remove-the-left-right-hand-margin-in-a-grouped-uitableview)), but cannot seem to get any to work quite right.

For example, if I try to solve the problem using contentInset (a common answer on SO):

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tableView.contentInset.top, -16, self.tableView.contentInset.bottom, self.tableView.contentInset.right);
    self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 33, 0, 0);
}
```

Then I end up with the gap on the right side of the tableview:

[image]

I get why it's happening, the entire tableview is just shifted over, as seen in the Debug View Hierarchy screen:

[image]

However, I've tried adjusting the tableView frame size to compensate, but it never seems to work correctly. Plus this seems hacky; there must be a better way.

For the record, here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get a cell that we can use]
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[PTStyleKit imageOfArrow]];

    // Create the attributed string (text + attributes)
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributes:attributes];

    // Set it in our UILabel and we are done!
    [cell.textLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];

    NSString* filename = [filenames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (filename == nil)
    {
        filename = cell.textLabel.text;
    }

    UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"medium-%@", filename]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageOne.CGImage scale:imageOne.size.height/44 orientation:imageOne.imageOrientation];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: looks like it's a problem with tableviewcell and not tableview itself. Can you also post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Novarg, just added it.

Comment: can you also debug that method and log the position of the `cell.imageView`?

Comment: @Novarg I am seeing x:0.000000, y: 0.000000 when I do `NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f", cell.imageView.frame.origin.x, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y);`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Novarg If you're noticing the strange small images being shown in the debug view hierarchy, I had assumed that was just a bug in Xcode 6.1.1, as they don't look that small/misplaced in the simulator.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was thinking that those coordinates were not 0, but now I do not have any idea how to fix it

Comment: You can allways make a custom cell with nib and from there things are easier and much customizable than using default UITableviewCell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the only solution I can find is to subclass UITableViewCell, and then override the layout of the imageView and textLabel. While researching this approach I found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106457/650558). (I guess I didn't realize this whole time I was searching for tableview behavior that was originally in iOS 6.)

My subclass has this one and only overridden method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Slide image to the left, eliminating gutter
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);

    // Slide text label to the left, and extend width by additional
    // space gained by eliminating the left-most gutter
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.imageView.frame.origin.x + self.imageView.frame.size.width + 15), 0, self.textLabel.frame.size.width + 15, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

My resulting tableview now looks exactly the way I want:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set a clear background to your table view and set the`contentInset` property.

**Code:**

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0);
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but increase the width of the table view by 15 pixels by setting the frame.

Answer (score 5):

**1. On iOS 13**

The key is, together with other things, to set
    `cell.contentView.layoutMargins` to `.zero`:

```
/// view controller
...
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
tableView.separatorInset = .zero
tableView.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
...

/// data source
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"
    cell.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
    cell.layoutMargins = .zero
    cell.contentView.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins = .zero
    return cell
}
```

If you are utilizing UITableViewController, in addition to all the above you also need to apply this:

```
tableViewController.viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false
```

**2. On iOS 12 and lower**

It seems that there is no way to use layoutMargins etc. to place the standard UITableViewCell.textLabel to zero offset in relation to the table. The easiest and the only way I found is to subclass the cell and override `layoutSubviews` like this:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    ...
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let leading = contentView.directionalLayoutMargins.leading
        textLabel?.frame.origin.x = leading
    }
    ...
}
```

And of course you need the layout margins to be properly set for that to work

Comment: damn, that's a lot of code to simply get rid of a margin. Worked though! Thank you

Comment: @AnatolyRudenko you can set Layout Margins in IB in the Size Instpector tab at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

I think I just came up with an easy solution, which I found over stackoverflow, one way to adjust cell margins, add this method in you code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]){
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

This solves my problem.

**Swift 3 and 4**

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset)) {
        cell.separatorInset = .zero
    }
    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins))) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

    if (cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.layoutMargins))) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    if tableView.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset)) {
        tableView.separatorInset = .zero
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8+

In your table view:

```
table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero     // or UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

You may also need:

```
table.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30640595/385273.

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
[cell.textLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
[cell.textLabel.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.contentView.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
[cell.textLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.contentView.leadingAnchor constant:22].active = YES;
```